# Classifying singularities of a complex function.

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to classify the singularities of a function $f(z)= \frac{\sin(z^2)}{ze^{\frac{1}{z-3}}}$. The singularities I see are $z=0,3$. I started with $z=0$, from thre I wanted to look at the Laurent series at the point. Now

$$\sin(z^2) = z^2 -\frac{z^5}{3!}+\frac{z^7}{5!}- \dots$$ 
Thus we can  observe

$$\frac{1}{ze^{\frac{1}{z-3}}}[z^2 -\frac{z^5}{3!}+\frac{z^7}{5!}- \dots]$$

Then
$$\frac{1}{e^{\frac{1}{z-3}}}[z^2 -\frac{z^5}{3!}+\frac{z^7}{5!}- \dots]$$

But then I am not sure how to precede to see the principal part of the Laurent series $(b_n)$ terms. I would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0):

We have $f(z)=\frac{\sin(z^2)}{z^2}ze^{- \frac{1}{z-3}}$. Since $\frac{\sin(z^2)}{z^2}$ has  a removable singularity  at $0$, $f$ has  a removable singularity  at $0$.

Use the power series of $e^w$ to see that $e^{- \frac{1}{z-3}}$ has an essential singularity at $3$. Thus $f$ has an essential singularity at $3$.

Comment: I am sorry can you expand on this a bit, I have a hard time seeing it.